# Visual Studio Code settings for C++ (a) static and (b) dynamic library linking

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, static-linking, dynamic-linking

Can I have some assistance configuring Visual Code (not Visual Studio) to build a C++ library?  Both static and most importantly a dynamic library?  Visual Code requires that you create a tasks.json file to tell VS Code how to build (compile) the program. This task will invoke the Microsoft C++ compiler to create an executable file based on the source code.

My current tasks.json is as follows:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "cl.exe build active file",
        "command": "cl.exe",
        "args": [
          "/Zi",
          "/EHsc",
          "/Fe:",
          "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
          "${file}"
        ],
        "problemMatcher": ["$msCompile"],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

In some scenarios, I need to link my main.cpp file dynamically (DLL) or statically (LIB).  My library code is very simple - just two functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "helloworld.h"

void connect()
{
    printf("Connected to C extension...\n");
}

//return random value in range of 0-50
int randNum()
{
    int nRand = rand() % 50; 
    return nRand;
}
 
//add two number and return value
int addNum(int a, int b)
{
    int nAdd = a + b;
    return nAdd;
}
```

I did my due diligence by doing a Google and Bing search but only landed on (a) Visual Studio and (b) .NET equivalents per the links below.  I'm in need of a solution for C++ static and dynamic libaries.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc

Thanks everyone.

**FWIW**....the contents of the helloworld.h at the top of my source code contains the following content:

```
 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void connect();
 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int randNum();
 extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int addNum(int a, int b);
```

...yet the build tools chain configured in VSCode (i.e. build tools for VS 2019, no IDE included) reports:

```
cl.exe /Zi /EHsc /nologo /Fe: C:\Users\foorbar\projects\CPP\helloworld.exe C:\Users\foobar\projects\CPP\helloworld.cpp
helloworld.cpp
   Creating library C:\Users\foobar\projects\CPP\helloworld.lib and object C:\Users\foobar\projects\CPP\helloworld.exp
LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined
```

Comment: One question per question please! Create a new one instead of adding a "bonus question", thus [edit] please!

Comment: Not the answer, but why use VSC with MSVC? I'd understand if you compiled with MinGW, but if you're using MSVC, might as well use VS itself?

Comment: Good question @HolyBlackCat.  Two reasons (1) I use Visual Code seamlessly between Linux, Mac and Windows.  (2) I'm creating a tutorial where Python users can load/integrate a C++ DLL.  To simplify the narrative, I am reducing the complexity of the environment to Visual Code only.  (3) That's why I intentionally installed VS2019 build tools only

Comment: You can find the documentation for cl.exe command line arguments online: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-by-category?view=msvc-160#linking

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, following your guidance to CL.EXE arguments , I added the switch /LD but doing so still fails with the following

 Creating library C:\Users\foobar\projects\CPP\helloworld.lib and object C:\Users\foobar\projects\CPP\helloworld.exp
LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined


I'm struggling to 

(a) establish a clear command line execution that links per the source above and 

(b) convert the arguments into Visual Code's "tasks.json" format

Comment: FYI, you can use MinGW (or perhaps Clang+MinGW) to make this completely cross-platform.